# Pandas: Trouble setting value for each column

Tags: python, pandas

I have an empty Pandas dataframe and I'm trying to add a row to it.  Here's what I mean:

```
text_img_count = len(BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml").find_all('img'))
    print 'img count: ', text_img_count

keys = ['text_img_count', 'text_vid_count', 'text_link_count', 'text_par_count', 'text_h1_count',
              'text_h2_count', 'text_h3_count', 'text_h4_count', 'text_h5_count', 'text_h6_count',
                       'text_bold_count', 'text_italic_count', 'text_table_count', 'text_word_length', 'text_char_length',
                       'text_capitals_count', 'text_sentences_count', 'text_middles_count', 'text_rows_count',
                       'text_nb_digits', 'title_char_length', 'title_word_length', 'title_nb_digits']
    values = [text_img_count, text_vid_count, text_link_count, text_par_count, text_h1_count,
                                   text_h2_count, text_h3_count, text_h4_count, text_h5_count, text_h6_count,
                                   text_bold_count, text_italic_count, text_table_count, text_word_length,
                                   text_char_length, text_capitals_count, text_sentences_count, text_middles_count,
                                   text_rows_count, text_nb_digits, title_char_length, title_word_length, title_nb_digits]

    numeric_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for key, value in zip(keys, values):
        numeric_df[key] = value

    print numeric_df.head()
```

However, the output is this:

```
img count:  2
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [text_img_count, text_vid_count, text_link_count, text_par_count, text_h1_count, text_h2_count, text_h3_count, text_h4_count, text_h5_count, text_h6_count, text_bold_count, text_italic_count, text_table_count, text_word_length, text_char_length, text_capitals_count, text_sentences_count, text_middles_count, text_rows_count, text_nb_digits, title_char_length, title_word_length, title_nb_digits]
Index: []

[0 rows x 23 columns]
```

This makes it seem like `numeric_df` is empty after I just assigned values for each of its columns.

What's going on?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do to add a column to the empty data frame is to append the information into a list and then give it a data frame structure. For example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
L=['a','b']

df['SomeName']=pd.DataFrame(L)
```

And you have to use pd.Series() if the list is make of numbers.